# Json Encode Issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a PHP file using json_encode to make a single call, but it does not go to the javascript... I have been trying for over a week... Maybe it is right in front of my face and I don't see it, so I will post it here to have a second set of eyes to maybe see what I don't... Does anyone see a problem, as I really dont...

Here is the json_encode getting the 3 array to make 1 call to the javascript...

```
$outarr['dayPowerP'] = $dayPowerP;
$outarr['monthPowerP'] = $monthPowerP;
$outarr['yearPowerP'] = $yearPowerP; 
echo json_encode($outarr);
```

Here is the output of the php file... The ID's and the values from the sql are right there....

```
{"dayPowerP":["13.2470"],"monthPowerP":["193.6810"],"yearPowerP":["989.6720"]}
```

Here is the ajax showing the post and Json...

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
$('#datepicker').datepicker({maxDate: 0, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', onSelect: function(dateText) {
            var myDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $('#apDiv1').html($.datepicker.formatDate('DD, d', myDate));
            $('#apDiv5').html($.datepicker.formatDate('MM', myDate));
            $('#apDiv7').html($.datepicker.formatDate('yy', myDate));           
            $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",   
            url: "clickdates.php",                  
            data: {choice: dateText}, 
            dataType: "json",  
            success: function(json_data) {  
            $('#apDiv2').html(json_data['dayPowerP']).show(); 
            $('#apDiv6').html(json_data['monthPowerP']).show();     
            $('#apDiv8').html(json_data['yearPowerP']).show(); 
           } 
        })           
    }});
});
```

To make it really clear... here is the full PHP file.

```
<?php  
$choice = (isset($_POST['choice'])) ? date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['choice'])) : date("Y-m-d"); 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxx");  
if (!$con)  {  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  }  
mysql_select_db("inverters", $con);  
$sql = "SELECT sum(power/1000) AS choice FROM feed WHERE date = '".$choice."' group by date"; $res = mysql_query($sql) or die('sql='.$sql."\n".mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$dayPowerP = array( $row['choice']);
?>
<?php 
$choice = (isset($_POST['choice'])) ? date("m",strtotime($_POST['choice'])) : date("m"); 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxx");  
if (!$con)  {  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  }  
mysql_select_db("inverters", $con);  
$sql = "SELECT sum(power/1000) AS choice FROM feed WHERE month(date) = '".$choice."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die('sql='.$sql."\n".mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$monthPowerP = array($row['choice']);
?>
<?php 
$choice = (isset($_POST['choice'])) ? date("Y",strtotime($_POST['choice'])) : date("Y"); $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxx");  
if (!$con)  {  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  }  
mysql_select_db("inverters", $con);  
$sql = "SELECT sum(power/1000) AS choice FROM feed WHERE year(date) = '".$choice."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die('sql='.$sql."\n".mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$yearPowerP = array( $row['choice']);
?>
<?php
$outarr['dayPowerP'] = $dayPowerP;
$outarr['monthPowerP'] = $monthPowerP;
$outarr['yearPowerP'] = $yearPowerP; 
echo json_encode($outarr);
?>
```

This is not complex code, so there has to be something minor I am not seeing or doing.

Thanks

Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mate. Json_encode doesn't support associative arrays.

"json_data['dayPowerP']" won't work.
json_data.dayPowerP
should work, it looks like that will return an array, so you need to typecast that to a float.

Can you please post the result of this: (see the console)

** console.log(json_data);**

specifically

```
    success: function(json_data) {  
console.log(json_data)

                $('#apDiv2').html(json_data['dayPowerP']).show(); 
                $('#apDiv6').html(json_data['monthPowerP']).show();     
                $('#apDiv8').html(json_data['yearPowerP']).show(); 
               }
```

If i'm right, then you should replace json_data['dayPowerP'] with json_data.dayPowerP[0]
in the success function and all should work correctly.

Comment: Looks like it supports them just fine, converting them into JSON objects as expected.

Comment: That was it !!!!! json_data.dayPowerP[0] did the job... THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!!!!! It feels like it is Christmas morning right now !!! Thanks again !

Comment: I wish I had a programming standard named after me.

Comment: no problems hkalan2007... tick my answer to accept it as the answer to the question :) Keyo: Lol.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to put each individual element in its own array; just embed them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
$('#apDiv2').html(json_data.dayPowerP[0]).show();